# Large deviations proof question

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Below is part of the proof of large deviations result. K is cumulant generating function. Can anyone explain how the last step follows?

[image]

This is page 157 of McCullagh's "Tensor Methods in Statistics"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think back to the proof of Chebychev's inequality, and you'll be home free.  The RHS of the next-to-the-last equality is $P[\exp (\xi (X - x)) \geq 1]$.  Now think of when $X$ has a PDF $f$ (but this is not required);  the probability is

$$
\int_{\exp (\xi (u - x))\geq 1} 1 \cdot f(u) \mathrm{d}u
$$

Now, over the region of integration the quantity $\exp (\xi (u - x)) \geq 1$, so by monotonicity we get that the above integral is at most

$$
\int_{\exp (\xi (u - x))\geq 1} \exp (\xi (u - x)) \cdot f(u) \mathrm{d}u
$$

and since the integrand is nonnegative this last integral is at most

$$
\int \exp (\xi (u - x)) \cdot f(u) \mathrm{d}u
$$

which is exactly $\exp[ -\xi x]$ multiplied by the moment generating function of $X$, denoted $M(\xi)$.  Finally, recognize $M = \exp (K)$ and we're finished.  By the way, the infimum holds because the inequality is true for every $\xi >0$.